# In VBA, how to handle same error differently from different variables?

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba

I have a VBA function in Access in the After_Update for a combobox that has two variables. The first one comes from the combobox and the second is a query result based on the first. I created some error handling to deal with Null values, but I would like to handle the errors differently depending on which value is Null. Sometimes users will enter a name in the combobox and then delete it, which makes the variable Null. If childID is Null that is not a problem and  I would like the function to simply exit. If visitID is Null, I would like it to display the error message box.  What I came up with displays the error for Null values from both variables.

```
On Error GoTo Error_Handle

childID = Me.cmbChildSearchFirst.Column(0)
visitid = DLookup("Visit.[VisitID]", "Q_VisitID_from_ChildID", "[ChildID] =" & childID)

Error_Handle:
If Err.Number = 94 Then
    MsgBox ("Child is not associated with any visit")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic outline:

```
childID = Me.cmbChildSearchFirst.Column(0)

'proceed only if not null.
If Not IsNull(childID) Then
    If Not IsNull(DLookup("Visit.[VisitID]", "Q_VisitID_from_ChildID", "[ChildID] =" & childID)) Then
        ....
    Else
        MsgBox ("Child is not associated with any visit")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Comment: This got me to the answer. I had to include "On Error Resume Next" and change the first if statement to "If IsNull(childID) Then Exit Sub   Else..."

Comment: Upvote this answer if it helped. Tnx. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235